# How does Java ZoneId.systemDefault() know about TimeZone if my computer doesn't connect to the Internet?

Tags: java, datetime

I'm new to Java8 Date And Time API and really curious about how a computer is aware of the time zones.

I already know a computer is aware of time by a small battery in its motherboard. Is the `TimeZone` similar?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen `TimeZone` was supplanted years ago by [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) with the adoption of JSR 310.

Comment: @BasilBourque `ZoneId systemDefault()` queries `TimeZone.getDefault()` according to the Javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

Your time, date and timezone is locally saved on your computer. Internet is used occasionally to sync with a global trusted time so your computer does not get out of sync.